# Как проверить ID записи на уникальность перед занесением в базу данных?

Tags: c#, access, ado.net

**ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ:**  С#, Access

**ИМЕЕТСЯ:**
В Access по средствам кода добавляются записи в БД с определённым ID.
Как проверить на уникальность ID добавляемой записи?

Т.е. если есть запись с ID имеется в базе, то мы её не добавляем, если нет то добавляем.
Если я правильно понимаю, то циклом это будет долго делаться?
Для добавления записи использую следующий код.

```
string connStringAcc = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}", textBox2.Text);
                using (OleDbConnection connAcc = new OleDbConnection(connStringAcc))
                {
                    connAcc.Open();
     
                    // добавим строку в таблицу hist
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO hist(url) VALUES('" + textBox5.Text + "')", connAcc);
     
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

**ВОПРОС**
    1. Как проверить на уникальность ID добавляемой записи?

Comment: Если в базе сделать эту колонку уникальной (`UNIQUE`), то можно просто добавлять и все, не уникальные добавляться не будут. Я правда по mysql сужу, но имхо в access так же должно работать.

Comment: примерно так: `'ALTER TABLE hist
ADD UNIQUE (id)'`. Ну и сам запрос поменять: `INSERT INTO hist(id, url) VALUES('" + someid + "', '" + textBox5.Text + "')"`

Comment: Оберните command.ExecuteNonQuery(); в try {...}  catch(). Есть смысл анализировать возможные исключения.

Answer (score 4):

ID у вас primary key? Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
var connStringAcc = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}", textBox2.Text);
int id = ...;
string url = textBox5.Text;
using (var connAcc = new OleDbConnection(connStringAcc))
{
    connAcc.Open();
    using (var cmd = connAcc.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO hist(id, url) 
            SELECT @id, @url WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM hist WHERE id = @id)";

        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
        {
            new OleDbParameter("@id", id),
            new OleDbParameter("@url", url)
        });

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```